# How to find element by multiline text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

How do you find an element by text if the text you're passing contains a break?

```
<div>
"Hello"
<br>
"World"
</div>
```

The following works:

```
text = 'Hello'  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()[contains(.,'%s')]]"%text)
```

This fails when the variable `text` is `'Hello World'`

Is there a way to ignore the line break?

Comment: You could try to remove all `<br>`s from your html that you are parsing

Comment: I have edited the answer, pls read it, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use normalize-space.

This works for me:

I ahve run the flask webserver:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return """<div>
    "Hello"
    <br>
    "World"
    </div>"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then I am trying to find the text:

```
from selenium import webdriver

text = 'Hello World'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://localhost:5000")
temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[normalize-space(//text() = '{0}')]".format(text))
print temp.text
```

It prints me the string.

You shouldn't use that ugly way to format string, it's the old way. Use the *format* function. It is more clear what you mean when you are writing it

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working.  
The definition I've found for normalize-space is as follows: "function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space."      
Is this function supposed to replace that line break with a single space?